# OpenCV3.0 new features tutorials

Tags: opencv

Excited by the many new features in OpenCv3.0. Can anyone point me to any tutorials specifically targeting the new features in Java?

- text detection
- many computational photography algorithms (HDR,    inpainting,
  edge-aware filters, superpixels, …)
- tracking and    optical flow algorithms new features, including line
  descriptors,
- KAZE/AKAZE general use optimization (hill climbing,    linear
  programming)
- greatly improved Python support, including    Python 3.0    support,
  many new tutorials & samples on how to use    OpenCV with
  Python.
- 2d shape matching module and 3d surface    matching module
- RGB-D    module
- VTK-based 3D visualization module